# Verify Bitcoin transaction Json

Tags: ajax, request, payment, bitcoin

I'm trying to verify my transaction with the URL JSON format of bitcoin for my app with a sample request. and I don't know if in this URL I have the answer for my case. I need to show data in a list. the information request I need is the payment it's ok. can you help me?

request: https://blockchain.info/tx/a47b5f0e31faaec5ff7d8d7c4662e174dae99ecbddd9bf32a846017b69c98794?format=json

```js
  $.ajax({
            url:'https://blockchain.info/tx/a47b5f0e31faaec5ff7d8d7c4662e174dae99ecbddd9bf32a846017b69c98794?format=json',
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'HTML',
             data: {param1: 'value1'},
         })
         .done(function(data) {
alert(data);
             console.log("success");
//check the json and print result
$('#answer').html("<li>"+data+"</li>");
         })
         .fail(function(data) {
alert("Error: " + data);
             console.log("error");
         })
         .always(function() {
             console.log("complete");
         });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="answer">waiting..</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i understood your question so you want to fetch data then print to the DOM a list of transaction values so i used fetch API to retrieve the transaction value then i grabbed the out transactions iterated over them and created an "li" for each value and append it to the DOM , hope this helps you

```js
let proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'

const list = document.getElementById('values')

const renderValues = (values) => {
 values.forEach(value => {
 const element = document.createElement('li')
 console.log(element)
 element.innerHTML = value.value
 list.appendChild(element)
 })
}
fetch(proxyUrl + 'https://blockchain.info/tx/a47b5f0e31faaec5ff7d8d7c4662e174dae99ecbddd9bf32a846017b69c98794?format=json').then(data => data.json()).then(res => renderValues(res.out)).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

```html
    <div id="answer">
    <ul id="values">
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: i need to check if my transaction it's ok and print in the DOM it's all.